# According to Datatype,Dynamically Create Control & Using those Control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to do a application in silverlight that contains follwing things

According to the datatype it receive from the class(which i am giving through wcf service)
it should create the control.
If it encounters string then a text box should be created dynamically.
If it encounters bool then a radiobutton should be created.

I want to acess those dynamically created controls.(as name is no static to refer in FindName())

How can i achive that.

Please help me with any related link or any code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, there's something called TemplateSelector, which does what you're asking for. In Silverlight, you have to write it yourself. [This should help you](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2009/03/16/Dynamic-Data-Forms-for-Silverlight-with-a-Data-Template-Selector-Control.aspx).